# How to convert flatten table to 2D Excel table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a "flatten" table with countries and years in Excel. eg.

```
Country      Year       Value
USA          1961       a
USA          1962       x
USA          1963       g
USA          1964       y
France       1961       u
              ...
```

And I'd like to have a two dimensional table as following:

```
        1961        1962        1963        1964
USA      a           x            g           y
France   u           e            h           a
Germany  o           x            n           p
```

Do you happen to know, how to do that programmatically in Excel using VBA. Many thanks in forward for any hint or advice.

Comment: how about just a pivot table to reorganize the data - then you can copy and paste it if you don't want to keep the pivot table?

Comment: Actually I need to do that programmatically in VBA... Any Ideas or piece of example code?

Comment: why do you *need* to do through VBA? And no, there is no sample code directly available for this specific problem (well, there may be, but you'd have to search for it). If you write some code to do it and get stuck and post what you tried here, we can then help you with it. But this is not a code writing service. That said, if you do need to use code, I would suggest programmatically making a pivot table to organize the data then copy / paste the new structure to where you need to go.

Comment: That's exactly what I need :-) I was searching through a bunch of sites and without any success :-( I'll try to place this task somewhere else. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Index/Match, as an array formula, to fill this in without VBA.  (If you need VBA, record this as a macro to see how the formula is entered, then just apply it to the empty table range):

`=INDEX($C$2:$C$6,MATCH($F3&G$2,$A$2:$A$6&$B$2:$B$6,0))`
(enter with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER)

Here's how the data's laid out, so you can see where I'm getting the ranges:

[image]

Then you can drag the formula over and down to fill in the rest of the table.  Natrually you would need to adjust the ranges used based on your data.